# MonoTouch - How do I declare UIPopoverController only when using an iPad device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller, public

As I understand from reading documentation, UIPopoverControllers are only supported on the iPad. Therefore if you try to declare a variable as a UIPopoverController and run the app in the iPhone simulator or on an iPhone, you get an error such as:

> UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

So I have a universal monotouch app I am trying out, where I would like to use a UIPopoverController when the user is using an iPad, for the iPhone I have another solution.

This is how I am declaring it at the moment, but obviously running on the iPhone does not work, and I get the above error message.

```
public partial class IOPSCalculatorViewController : UIViewController
{

    static bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone; }
    }

    static bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsIPAD {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad; }
    }

    UIPopoverController DetailViewPopover = new UIPopoverController(new PopoverContentViewController());
}
```

How can I only declare the:

```
UIPopoverController DetailViewPopover = new UIPopoverController(new PopoverContentViewController());
```

part if the device is an iPad? I need the UIPopoverController to be in the public partial class so that I can access it publically in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring and allocating in one line just split it in two lines. E.g.

```
UIPopoverController DetailViewPopover = null;

if (IOPSCalculatorViewController.UserInterfaceIdiomIsIPAD) {
    DetailViewPopover = new UIPopoverController (new PopoverContentViewController ());
}
```

That will also work if `DetailViewPopover` is a (public) field instead of an instance variable and, as long as the `UIPopoverController` constructor is not invoked, you won't be getting the error.

Comment: Thank you @poupou! I see, so declaring it has null means that the iPhone will still enumerate this code, but as it is null it does not have an issue with this statement? I then go into device-specific code for the iPad and assign it a value when needed. This works great after testing :)

Comment: Yes, Apple does the device-check inside the `init` (which for MonoTouch is mapped to the constructor). So simply having the variable, unassigned, is ok (for iPhones).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what is your current device and write code for iphone and iPad as well. here is a snap of code that I've used in my case.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
     {
        //Do your coding here
     }
     else {
         if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible]){
             contact = [[[ContactViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
             popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contact] retain];
             [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(400.0f, 400.0f)];
             [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(230, 860, 320.0f, 320.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
             [popoverController release];
         }else{
             [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
         }
     }
```

hope this will help you. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Hi @surya-kant thanks for the reply, but I was kind of aware of determining the device type first and then declaring the variable. However, declaring my PopOverController in an IF statement means that it will only be available for use within this IF statement. I need to declare it at the public level, however I cannot use IF statements in this area. Also, I am using C# (MonoTouch!)